# Using implied as an adjective

Tags: usage

According to the dictionary the word **implied** is an adjective.
It is is also the past tense of imply.

I have been trying to find some examples of where implied is used as an **everyday** **adjective** and only seem to be able to find it used as a technical description in law.

Actually, even the Cambridge dictionary labels it as an adjective with Law written beside it in parenthesis.

Is it possible that this adjective's usage is only limited to the field of law?
If not, can someone give me some everyday examples of how it is used.

Thank you

Comment: If you google **implied adjective**, you will find several sites that answer your question. eg https://www.dictionary.com/browse/implied

Comment: – Ronald Sole Thank you for response.  I have looked at most of the online dictionaries, but only seem to find this adjective being used in a very technical and formal manner (in law, politics etc). I can't seem to find any simple sentence examples where the word is used in everyday life, (lots of examples for it being used as a verb).

Comment: In order for a word to have a tense, it must at least be based on a verb. While *implied* can be used adjectivally, *imply* is a verb. In fact, Merriam-Webster *only* lists its [verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imply) form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Implied` is definitely in common use as an adjective and is not just used in law.

Here are some examples:

> He told me he was going to "see a man about about a dog", but I think there was an **implied** meaning in that.
>
> I know the author doesn't tell you that the girl was frightened, but that meaning seems **implied**.
>
> What a horrible thing **to imply**!
>
> The plot **implied** earlier was that the couple would not get married after all.

Verb phrases often can act as different parts of speech in English, it's not just `implied`.   When they do this, it is called `verbal use` and they are called  `verbals`.  This is what happens in the last two examples above.

In the first two examples, however, `implied` is a true adjective (since it does not take a subject!) and this use is called `deverbal`; `implied` functions like an ordinary adjective there and this is what the dictionary means when it says `implied` can be an adjective.

It is illustrative to compare (both correct!)

> The plot implied earlier was that the couple would not get married after all.
>
> The plot implied earlier that the couple would not get married after all.

In the first sentence, `implied` is an adjective that modifies `plot`.  In the second sentence, `implied` is a past tense verb whose subject is `the plot`.

Comment: BadZen Thank you very much for your detailed and helpful answer.

Comment: Despite being correct, the use of "implied" as an adjective has always bothered me, because it sounds like a past tense verb, and because it is often used when the word "implicit" would be a better choice. For example, "Overly fundamental rules are not written in the rulebook because they're implied."

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick -  It's not just "implied"! In English, the past participle forms of verbs are very often used as adjectives, these often end in -ed as in the above example.  Sometimes the present tense is used as well - these adjectives often end with -ing.  The color of tense is often present when these are used, so when something is "implied" it can in fact indicate that an implication was made in the past!